# How does the JSON Parser work exactly?

Tags: java

Ok so I have been given a project to build a TST(Completed) and am supposed to use JSON parser on a Dictionary file to load the values into my Data structure and was given a basic class of code for example. This is the very first Time I have ever been exposed to this utility and I have absolutely no idea on how it works. Typically when I want to parse an input i would simply do something along the lines of

```
String[] parse = txt.split("|");
```

yet this obviously isn't going to work, So In the end of the code I see where it differentiates (or i think it does anyways) The Key & The Value, I need to read those line by line to feed into a another method in which I would typically do with a for Loop yet have no clue as to what syntax this method even uses

```
for(int i = 0; i < JSON.Size; i++) {
   first = get.JSON_Key(i);
   last = get.JSON_Value(i);
   tst.put(key, value);
}
```

So obviously that would be better suited pseudo code, I don't know if this is storing separate values in separate containers and if so what to use to get a hold of those values the following is the example code we were given

```
public class ReadJSON
{   
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String infile = "dictionary.json";
        JsonReader jsonReader;
        JsonObject jobj = null;
        try
        {
            jsonReader = Json.createReader( new FileReader(infile) );
            // assumes the top level JSON entity is an "Object", i.e. a dictionary
            jobj = jsonReader.readObject();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not find the file to read: ");
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
        catch(JsonParsingException e)
        {
            System.out.println("There is a problem with the JSON syntax; could not parse: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(JsonException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not create a JSON object: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException e)
        {
            System.out.println("JSON input was already read or the object was closed: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if( jobj == null )
            return;

            Iterator< Map.Entry<String,JsonValue> > it = jobj.entrySet().iterator();//Not sure what this is doing
            Map.Entry<String,JsonValue> me = it.next();//not sure what this is doing
            String word = me.getKey();
            String definition = me.getValue().toString();

            for(int i =0; i < jsonReader.; i++) {

        }   
    }
}
```

Any help in understanding this a bit more and correct syntax for that for loop would be appreciated

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of the classes and methods you're using? Because that's what it's for: explaining what methods do.

Comment: First go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It's quite simple and only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Next you can look at any of several open-source JSON packages, or simply accept that the parsers are magic, understanding that there's a 1:1 mapping between JSON "object" and "array" and Java's "Map" and "List".  The only thing really tricky is the numbers and Boolean values, which are occasionally not mapped the exact way you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

The code is using JSR 353: Java API for JSON Processing. Look at the https://jsonp.java.net/.

Comment: Thank you that Was helpful, I have found more that is looking familiar, The JSON Interface was all I could find on Javadocs and really wasn't helpful